# XDebug installed but it doesn't show in phpinfo()

Tags: linux, xdebug, php-extension, php

I want to print the phpinfo() function to see if some modules are installed or not:

```
<?php

// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();

// Show just the module information.
// phpinfo(8) yields identical results.
phpinfo(INFO_MODULES);
```

the result of commands:

```
php -m | grep -i xdebug
xdebug
Xdebug
```

AND

```
php -v
PHP 5.6.37 (cli) (built: Sep  9 2018 15:55:18) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.5.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2017, by Derick Rethans
    with Suhosin v0.9.38, Copyright (c) 2007-2015, by SektionEins GmbH
```

### Update

I have added the following extensions and xdebugger parameters:(`/usr/local/php56/lib/php.ini`)

```
[Zend]
zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.6.so   
zend_extension_ts=/usr/local/lib/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.6_ts.so
zend_extension=/usr/local/lsws/lsphp5/lib/php/modules/xdebug.so

[xdebug]
;Remote settings
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
.
.
.
```

You see there is no error but I can't use xdebug.

### UPDATE 2

This shows what my php.ini file is:

```
php -i | grep "Loaded Conf"
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/php56/lib/php.ini
```

Comment: Have you added that extension in php.ini file ?

Comment: @Manmohan I updated. thank you. I don't know what the problem is...

Comment: If you have a webserver with PHP support running did you restart it?

Comment: Yes, I restarted litespeed and also I rebooted my server (CentOS 7)

Comment: Are you **not** seeing XDEBUG information in `phpinfo()`?  Or are you seeing it and XDEBUG is just not working for you?  

What editor/IDE are you using?

Comment: I can't see xdebug in phpinfo() so it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling and recompiling and puting softlink resolved the problem:

```
ln -s /usr/local/php56/lib/php.ini /usr/local/lsws/lsphp5/lib/php.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your php.ini in phpinfo() on access over http, probably you have two php on your machine php-cli and php for your apache or nginx etc.

Comment: Thanks, I see `Configuration File (php.ini) Path /usr/local/lsws/lsphp5/lib`, but there are no php.ini in this path

Comment: You see I updated question. my `php.ini` file is in `/usr/local/php56/lib/php.ini`